# Using lookup objects fields in Formula in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Can i create a formula using a lookup object fields? For instance i have a custom object and got a lookup with account

i need a formula which uses a field from the account object

For eg.

```
 "PJ_"&SHORTNAME&"_"&UNIQUE-SEQ-NUM (UNIQUE)
```

Where shortname is a field in account object.. If using formaula is not possible is there anyway to achieve it?

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your lookup field in the custom object is called account, then you can traverse the relationship in your formula by using Account__r, e.g

```
"PJ_" & Account__r.Name
```

Will concat in the related accounts name value